# Webpack Dev Server Live Reloads Only Once - Does Not Pick Up Changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am having a weird issue with Webpack dev server. Basically upon the first change to my source code, it runs.

Thereafter, when I hit save, it says the following in the web console:

`[WDS] Nothing changed.`

But clearly this is false as I am changing text in my source code. Can someone please explain what could be going wrong.

**webpack.dev.config.js**:

```
const path = require('path')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
    },

    devServer: {
        open: true,
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        writeToDisk: true,
        index: 'index.html',
        port: 9090,
        hot: true,
        inline: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'My App - Dev',
            template: './src/index.hbs',
            description: 'Development Mode',
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                use: ['file-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/env'],
                        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.hbs$/,
                use: ['handlebars-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

My directory structure:

[image]